# What volume exactly does the $V$ term in ideal gas equation represent?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas, kinetic-theory, volume

According to kinetic theory of gases 'the actual volume occupied by the gas molecules are negligible in comparison to the volume of the container.'

I believe that this assumption is significant because this leads to the volume correction in Van-der-Waals real gas equation.
I wonder what difference it is going to make even if do not assume this.

What volume does exactly the $V$ term in ideal gas equation represent?

Comment: For an ideal gas it's the volume of the container, for non-ideal gases it's only an approximate "effective" volume. The reason that it makes sense to talk about it lies in the "hardness" of effective molecular potentials. One can flex molecules a little bit and one can rotate them and certain subgroups with relatively little energy input, but compressing the volume that the electron orbitals take in requires a lot of energy, which makes molecules fuzzy on the outside, but very "hard" on the inside.

Comment: Think about condensation. In this regime the zero own volume approximation is certainly not valid.

Answer (score 1):

A gas can be approximated as an ideal gas. You then assume that the particles don't feel each other and that they are infinitely small. The potential is zero. The particles can only have kinetic energy. If you would make a simulation of such a system the particles can literally move through each other.
If you make this ideal gas approximation, it is relatively easy to derive the ideal gas law: $$p V = N k_\mathrm b T.$$ Here $V$ is the volume of the system where the particles are confined in.
The ideal gas approximation is decent for some cases and becomes exact when the density goes to zero. (For argon I know that the ideal gas law is a good approximation for relatively high densities).

The van der Waals formula is derived in a very similar way as the ideal gas law, but now instead of assuming that the particles have no volume you assume that every particle occupies some volume. In the van der Waals formula you will find a term: $(V - Nb)$, where $b$ is the volume of each particle and $N$ is the number of particles.
Usually in the van der Waals equation you also model that the particles attract each other when they are far apart, which also gives a correction. (To calculate this correction, some mean field is often assumed).

Answer (score 0):

You can model the gas a a collection of hard spheres of some radius $r$, and do the correction relative to the limit as $r\to\infty$ perturbatively.  What you find is that for a fixed pressure and temperature amd number of molecules the first order correction to the law replaces $V$ with $V-\frac{4n\pi r^3}{3}$.  This tells you that the volume to use is the container volume minus the sum of the volumes of the molecules.

However, it is not too hard to do a second-order perturbative correction to that approximation, and you find that for a fixed volume, temperature, and number of molecules the pressure is slightly less than the first-order approximation would predict. This effect is very small until the volume of the molecules becomes comparable to (say at least a few percent of) the available volume.  For a gas like Argon, I think this can be confirmed by measurements in the lab.  For most gasses, you start becoming a liquid before that (the hard sphere approximation breaks down).